# How to get date from day of year

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I get `date` from `day of year` in C#?

I have this code :

```
int a = 53;   // This is the day of year value, that I got previously
string b = Convert.ToDateTime(a).ToString();   // Trying to get the date
```

I need to get the value `22.2.2014`. But this doesn't work, what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you probably need to use TimeSpan.FromDays(x): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromdays(v=vs.110).aspx then use the value to convert it to DateTime.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
int dayOfYear = 53;
int year = DateTime.Now.Year; //Or any year you want
DateTime theDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(dayOfYear - 1);
string b = theDate.ToString("d.M.yyyy");   // The date in requested format
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly, just had to correct toString as ToString

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want the current year?

```
int a = 53;
DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1,1).AddDays(a -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 53;
var dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1).AddDays(a - 1);
string b = dt.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DateTime.AddDays()
```

Initialize a date to start of the year , then just add `a` to that using this function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx