# Convert Day count into months and year in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have day count available from 1 to 365 which i want to convert into day-month-year. I know that there is a leap year problem and inital search suggest that it is difficult to write an algorithm without any context. For keeping in mind this fact, i have also got the **year** detail.

```
 string GetDate(int day, int year)
    {
        ///logic to convert any day (1-365) with an year context

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get date from day of year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960499/how-to-get-date-from-day-of-year)

Comment: Regarding "... there is a leap year problem ..." - In general, leap years are not a *problem*, they are just part of how the Gregorian calendar works.  The only *problem* is that you have limited the upper bound to 365.  It should be from 1 to 366, and you can use `DateTime.IsLeapYear` to check if 366 is valid within the given year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(day-1).ToString();
```

you should be validating your input too and consider if its better to return a date and not just a string

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy using Date functions. You need to validate the values passed as parameter and output as well. Day must start from 1.

```
string GetDate(int day, int year)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(day - 1);
    return date.ToString(); 
}
```